# CHtml textfield text color same as placeholder color

Tags: php, yii, placeholder, yii-chtml

I have this:

```
CHtml::textField("Atava[admin_panel][0][u_type]", '', array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128,'encode'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Placeholder content') );
```

My problem is:

when I add text to the text field, the placeholder text disappears (as it should)

But the added text gets the same color as the Placeholder text color(light grey).

I want the added text to have the default color (like it has without a placeholder)

any ideas??

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't mind the color of the Placeholder text- light grey is good, My problem is that after I add text to the text field - the added text has the same color as the place holder text(light grey), I want it to have its regular color.

Answer (score 1):

Set css styles for placeholder http://jsfiddle.net/SKS23/

```
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
*:-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 4-18 */
    color: red;
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 19+ */
    color: red;
}
*:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't mind the color of the Placeholder text- light grey is good, My problem is that after I add text to the text field - the added text has the same color as the place holder text(light grey), I want it to have its regular color

Comment: @AsafMaoz Then check css styles for input field